# Custom SINGLE page with custom metaboxes and custom template

Tags: pages, metabox, templates

I run in this situation where I must create complex contacts page with custom template, custom meta boxes.

I know how to make custom post type, add meta boxes and display all information in custom template. Problem is I don't need 200 contacts pages that custom post type allows, just one.

Is there way to create this page under pages section?

Similar to selecting dropdown template for page just for admin side that changes page meta box structure.

Comment: Ok, answer was pretty easy. It is possible hide, show metaboxes with jquery and make logic based on that.

Comment: Go on and add an answer! With some code and a explanation. There is even a [badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/self-learner) you can earn for that!

Answer (score 0):

Simlified function, maybe will help someone:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#page_template").change(function() {
        if($('#page_template').val() != 'page-contacts.php') {
            // show the meta box
            $('#postdivrich').show();
        } else {
            // hide your meta box
            $('#postdivrich').hide();
        }
    }).change();         
});
```

**Of course** it lacks controls what fields will be submitted, because jQuery just hides them. As I am coding it for one-admin user it is not big deal, helps to get cleaner layout. But in other cases it might be dangerous.